# Why CPython need Bytecode like LOAD_X?

Tags: python, cpython

Let's take a look at the bytecode of one simple function:

```
>>> def func(a):
...     print a
... 
>>> dis.dis(func)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              3 PRINT_ITEM          
              4 PRINT_NEWLINE       
              5 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              8 RETURN_VALUE
```

Why don't we just compile it into something like:

```
PRINT_ITEM               0 (a)         
PRINT_NEWLINE       
RETURN_VALUE             0 (None)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about this, but I think that some instructions like "PRINT_ITEM" work on a register. Most machines (even virtual machines) work this way: they use a small set of very simple instructions. By combining and executing many instructions, you can do complex things. The set of available instructions is limited.

Answer (score 0):

Python virtual machine uses stack architecture. It means that data (that is going to be processed) is taken from a FIFO structure into a virtual functional blocks.

Going your function line by line

1. `LOAD_FAST 0 (a)` places variable `a` from the main memory to the top of the stack (TOS)
2. `PRINT_ITEM` takes a TOS item, converts it to string (using **str** or **repr** method) and puts it in the `stdout`
3. `PRINT_NEWLINE` seems to be a shortcut for `LOAD_FAST 0 ('\n'); PRINT_ITEM`
4. `LOAD_CONST  0 (None)` places `None` singleton object on the TOS
5. `RETURN_VALUE` returns TOS from the funtion.

Regarding your question, why it's not just a three lines of assembly. Short assembly doesn't necessarily means fast program. This holds true for real silicon processors as well as for virtual machines.

Second thing is that it might be easier for Python dev team to stick to the stack virtual machine architecture rather than implementing another high level intermediate language. Also simpler commands allows us to optimize their order, but I'm not sure if CPython uses this advantage (refer to [pipelining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_pipelining) for details).

**Edit**

Another reading about `long code of simple commands` vs. `short code of complex commands` is [RISC vs. CISC](http://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/courses/soco/projects/risc/risccisc/)